# Compare list from file with multiples lines and count matches

Tags: python, list

I have a file with several lists in one file and I would like to compare and count occurrences with a list in my code.
Example file:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10
10, 20, 30 ,40 50, 60
25, 35, 45, 55, 65, 75
```

And my code i have the list with results:

```
list = [1, 5, 10, 20, 30]
```

Output expected:

```
Line 1 = 3 
Line 2 = 3
Line 3 = 0
```

Already tried with sum in loop for but is working just first line:

```
count = sum(f in a for f in list)
print(count)
```

Thanks to anyone who can help.

Comment: File is wrong, correct is: 
`1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10`
`10, 20, 30 ,40 50, 60`
`25, 35, 45, 55, 65, 75`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Your logic is close but you need to loop through each line as well. Also don't shadow builtins like `list`

```
numbers = {1, 5, 10, 20, 30} # Set's are better for lookup

with open("filename.txt") as infile:
    for i, line in enumerate(infile, 1):
        count = sum(int(n) in numbers for n in line.split(", "))
        print(f"Line {i} = {count}")
```

Comment: following the answer above, I'm a beginner in python and it helped a lot both ways on how to do it, I was lost in the for loop, thanks a lot!